# Vector to raster graphics for draft mode

Tags: graphics, conversion

I'm writing a document which has many plots with quite a lot of data points. Those plots are stored as `.pdf` vector images and their rendering takes a lot of time. So every time I stumble upon a page with one of those, my editor freezes for a solid minute.

I know that graphicsx has a draft option but that hides the images which is not a very good solution since then I can't tell the images apart just by the filename. Those are results of experimental runs with quite generic names.

Is there perhaps a way to rasterize the images (e.g. into `.png`) in draft mode and use the original `.pdf` in final mode? I know that I could use ImageMagick or whatever external tools to do the conversion but that seems like a lot of extra work since I would need to add every image to a makefile and duplicate the `\includegraphics` for draft and final.

There are some parameters of graphicsx such as `type` or `command` which are not explained in the documentation. Could this perhaps be achieved using one of those? Could I perhaps hook the `\includegraphics` and call an external command? I would manage writing the command but I have no Idea how hooks work in LaTeX.

Otherwise, I'm well aware of the fact that raster graphics are inferior to vector graphics as far as the quality is concerned. I'm going to use vector graphics in the final version. This is intended solely for quick draft preview.

Comment: It may be possible to reduce the size of the vector images without affecting their quality. What software produced them?

Comment: @IanThompson Those were made with MS Excel. I was already thinking about down-sampling the data series but that would also be a bit laborous.

Comment: `texdoc graphicx` page 10 lists both type and command keys. Which documentation did you use?

Comment: Not a TeX solution, but may serve. Can you prepare one document with all the images and the filenames, then scroll in that one to see relevant figures when editing and compiling the text in graphicx draft mode?

Comment: There is a utility called [polygone](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/index.htm) which can sometimes reduce the size of `eps` files by a substantial percentage. I've never tried it with files from Excel, though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does list them (otherwise I wouldn't know about them in the first place), but there are no expected values or examples for those. I have no idea what they do.

Comment: @EthanBolker well .. that's not much better than looking at the files by file name so not much improvement over bare draft mode. Also I'm writing the document and adding new figures so I would have to generate / copy / reopen the doc. So not much help but thanks for the constructive idea. I sure do appreciate that you took your time to think about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The search path for the images can be changed:

- `\graphicspath` with a directory for PDF images or it counterparts, the PNG images.
- `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` can be used to change the order, which extension is used first, when the image file was given without extension. Package `grfext` provides an interface for changing the setting.

Package `epstopdf` can be used to call the conversion from PDF to PNG automatically, if pdfTeX or luaTeX is used and the shell escape feature is enabled.

Example:

If `\mydraft` is defined to be `Y` (`\let\mydraft=Y`), then the rule for the extension `.pdf` is overwritten to make a conversion to `.png` via ImageMagick's `convert`. Otherwise the `.pdf` extension is preferred.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grfext}

\ifx\mydraft Y
  \usepackage{epstopdf-base}
  \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf}{png}{.png}{%
    convert #1 \OutputFile
  }  
  \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.PDF}{png}{.png}{%
    convert #1 \OutputFile
  }  
\else
  \PrependGraphicsExtension*{.pdf}
\fi

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image}
\end{document}
```

The special draft mode is enabled by `\let\mydraft=Y`, which can also be given on the command line, e.g.:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape "\let\mydraft=Y\input{mydocument}"
```

Then `image.pdf` is converted and included as `image-pdf-converted-to.png`.

Otherwise, `image.pdf` is included, even if `image.png` lies around.

### Key for `\includegraphics`

The conversion feature can also be limited to `\includegraphics` by use of a key `pdfpng`. The key code changes the graphics rule for `.pdf` files to convert them to PNG. If `\mydraft` is not `Y`, then the key is a no-op.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grfext}

\ifx\mydraft Y
  \usepackage{epstopdf-base}
  \csname define@key\endcsname{Gin}{pdfpng}[]{%
    \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf}{png}{.png}{%
      convert ##1 \OutputFile
    }%
  }
\else
  \PrependGraphicsExtensions*{.pdf}
  \csname define@key\endcsname{Gin}{pdfpng}[]{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image1}
\includegraphics[pdfpng]{image2-converted-to-png-when-mydraft}
\includegraphics{image3}
\end{document}
```

(`\define@key` can be used instead of `\csname define@key\endcsname`, when `\makeatletter` is active.)

Comment: Wow, tremendous solution I must say! I have one issue though, the tex is using the new file names but I'm getting `Package pdftex.def Error: File 'figs/example_matrix-pdf-converted-to.png' not found.` And the file is really not there. I have made sure that convert is in the path. Any ideas what might be the problem? Maybe some unwanted interaction with other packages? I'm using classicthesis. Or did I misunderstand and do I have to do the conversions manually?

Comment: Ah ha, I'm using miktex so rather than the *mandatory* `--shell-escape`, I need to use `--enable-write18`.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a way to enable this only for selected images? I was thinking along the lines of making a dummy extension (e.g. `.df2ng`) and then using one of `ext`, `type` or `read` to trigger the conversion (the file would still be `.pdf` same as the others), only I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: @theswine See updated answer.

Comment: To whom it may concern, some of the pdfs I had were not of standard page size and imagemagick was failing on them. So I made a script called `convert.bat` and put it next to the `.tex` file to be picked up first and in it I call `gs` as `gswin32c -o "%2" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r72x72 -dUseCropBox -dFitPage "%1" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE`. The key flags here are `dUseCropBox -dFitPage` which need to be on the command line *before* the input file.